# $(\varepsilon, \delta)$ for continuity of a multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

> Define $f : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$, $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
>       0 & (x,y) =  0 \\
>       \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y) \ne 0
>    \end{cases} $$ Determine if $f$ is continuous.

At $\Bbb R^2_{\ne 0}$ we have that $f$ is continuous. In order to see if it's continuous at the origin I was approaching it using epsilon-delta. We have that $|f(x,y) - f(0,0)| < \varepsilon$ whenever $\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta$.

Now $$|f(x,y)-f(0,0)| = \frac{|xy||x^2-y^2|}{|x^2+y^2|} \leqslant \frac{|xy||x^2+y^2|}{|x^2+y^2|} =|xy|.$$

However I'm losing $x^2+y^2$ here since that's what I would need for $\delta$. What am I missing in my approach here? Is there another way I could bound this?

Comment: Hint $(|x|-|y|)^2\ge 0$ and devellop, can you bound $|xy|$ now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**: Remember that $|x|,|y|\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: This is Cauchy-Schwarz $|x||y| \leqslant \|xy\|$?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are real numbers here! What you just wrote makes no sense.

Comment: Ah yes... sorry. However I have the multiplication $|xy|$. I should then get $|xy| \leqslant \sqrt{x^2+y^2}^2 = x^2 + y^2 < \delta^2$?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing it would be to evaluate:
$$L=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$$
now if we use polar coordinates we know that:
$$x^2+y^2=r^2,x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$$
s0:
$$L=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{r^4\sin\theta\cos\theta(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)}{r^2}=\lim_{r\to0}r^2\frac{\sin(2\theta)\cos(2\theta)}{2}=\lim_{r\to0}r^2\frac{\sin(4\theta)}{4}=0$$
and since $\theta$ does not affect this limit this is true whichever direction it is approached from, meaning the function is continuous for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 0):

For all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ we have
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
&2|xy|\le x^2+y^2\\[4pt]
&|x^2-y^2|\le x^2+y^2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
hence for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2{\setminus}\{(0,0)\}$ we have
$$
2|f(x,y)|
=
\frac
{(2|xy|)(|x^2-y^2|)}
{x^2+y^2}
\le
\frac
{(x^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2)}
{x^2+y^2}
=
x^2+y^2
$$
which approaches $0$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$.